# Message latencies with CPU under-utilization

Tags: java, akka, akka-actor

We've got a Java app where we basically use three dispatcher pools to handle processing tasks:

1. Convert incoming messages (from RabbitMQ queues) into another format
2. Serialize messages
3. Push serialized messages to another RabbitMQ server

The thing, where we don't know how to start fixing it, is, that we have latencies at the first one. In other words, when we measure the time between "tell" and the start of doing the conversion in an actor, there is (not always, but too often) a delay of up to 500ms. Especially strange is that the CPUs are heavily under-utilized (10-15%) and the mailboxes are pretty much empty all of the time, no huge amount of messages waiting to be processed. Our understanding was that Akka typically would utilize CPUs much better than that?

The conversion is non-blocking and does not require I/O. There are approx. 200 actors running on that dispatcher, which is configured with throughput 2 and has 8 threads.

The system itself has 16 CPUs with around 400+ threads running, most of the passive, of course.

Interestingly enough, the other steps do not see such delays, but that can probably explained by the fact that the first step already "spreads" the messages so that the other steps/pools can easily digest them.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause such latencies and CPU under-utilization and how you normally go improving things there?

Comment: Did you configure your own dispatcher like here https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/dispatchers.html#setting-the-dispatcher-for-an-actor ? I think it is worth while to post the configuration of your dispatcher in the question.

Comment: As mentioned above, the three actor groups (converting, serializing, pushing) are running each on their own dispatcher, the converting one with a thread-pool-executor, fixed-pool-size of 8 and throughput 2, nothing special there.